# Get BitBucket users, groups, permissions

Tags: python, python-2.7, bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I am trying to write python script to get list of BitBucket users, groups and permissions to repositories. Can someone provide an example how to do this using python?

Comment: Atlassian has a „[Use the Bitbucket Cloud REST APIs](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-the-bitbucket-cloud-rest-apis-222724129.html)“ document which may be a starting point. And there are Python packages like [Bitbucket-API](https://bitbucket-api.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used pure BitBucket rest api. Use endpoint like /api/1.0/privileges/{project.name} and pase json. Everything works fine.